Pandas complex groupby using match criteria in another table
I am having a hard time describing this issue in a general way that would make the question title useful. But here it is. I am trying to merge or group rows in a table based on ids in a column that are declared to belong to certain groups according to a different table. It is complicated further by the ids being composite objects spread across two columns. Here is a toy version of it and a solution that works, but is terribly inefficient:
# Inputs:

columns = ["time", "id1_list", "id2_list", "id3"]
data = [(1, ("A", "B"), (1, 2), 1),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (2, 3), 2),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (4, 5), 3),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (6, 7), 4),        
        (1, ("A", "C"), (1, 1), 5),
        (2, ("A", "B"), (1, 3), 1),
        (2, ("A", "B"), (2, 3), 2),        
        (2, ("A", "B"), (4, 3), 3),
        (2, ("A", "C"), (1, 1), 4)]

merge_cols = ["time", "id1", "id2_lists"]
merge_data = [(1, "A", ((1, 2), (3, 4))),
              (1, "B", ((3, 5),)),
              (2, "A", ((1, 2), (3, 4))),
              (2, "B", ((3, 5),))]

output_columns = ["time", "id3_lists"]
expected_output = [(1, ((1, 2, 3, 5), (4,))),
                   (2, ((1, 2, 3, 4),))]

Inefficient solution:
# Group by time
df_g = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).groupby("time")
df_merge_data_g = pd.DataFrame(merge_data, columns=merge_cols).groupby("time")


def match(g, id3_A, id3_B, df_merge_data_t):
    # print(df_LR_t)
    # Get id match info
    rowA = g.query("id3==@id3_A").iloc[0]
    rowB = g.query("id3==@id3_B").iloc[0]
    id1sA = rowA["id1_list"]
    id1sB = rowB["id1_list"]
    id2sA = rowA["id2_list"]
    id2sB = rowB["id2_list"]
    matched = False
    for id1_A, id2_A in zip(id1sA, id2sA):
        if matched: break           
        for id1_B, id2_B in zip(id1sB, id2sB):
            if matched: break
            if id1_A==id1_B:
                # print(id1_A, id2_A, id1_B, id2_B)
                match_groups = df_merge_data_t.query("id1==@id1_A")["id2_lists"].iloc[0]                 
                # print(match_groups)
                for match_g in match_groups:
                    # print(match_g)
                    # print(id2_A in match_g, id2_B in match_g)
                    if id2_A in match_g and id2_B in match_g:
                        matched = True
                        break
    # print("matched:", matched)
    return matched


def merge(data):
    for x in set(data):
        for y in set(data):
            if x == y:
                continue
            if not x.isdisjoint(y):
                data.remove(x)
                data.remove(y)
                data.add(x.union(y))
                return merge(data)
    return data


def get_match_groups(g):
    #print(g)    
    df_merge_data_t = df_merge_data_g.get_group(g.name)
    
    # Form all pairings of items to be matched
    pairs = list(itertools.combinations(g.id3, 2))
    
    # Check each pair for match
    matched_pairs = set(frozenset(pair) for pair in pairs if match(g, *pair, df_merge_data_t))

    print("matched_pairs")
    print(matched_pairs)
    
    # Merge pairs with common elements to get connected groups of matches
    merged_matches = merge(matched_pairs)
    
    # Add back any items that weren't matched with anything as singleton groups
    unused = set(frozenset((id3,)) for id3 in set(g.id3) if not any(id3 in g for g in merged_matches))
    merged_matches.update(unused)
    
    return merged_matches


out = df_g.apply(get_match_groups, include_groups=False)

Output:
time
1    {(1, 2, 3, 5), (4)}
2         {(1, 2, 3, 4)}
dtype: object

Expected output:
pd.DataFrame(expected_output, columns=output_columns)["id3_lists"]

0    ((1, 2, 3, 5), (4,))
1    ((1, 2, 3, 4))
Name: id3_lists, dtype: object

So in words: We have the table data. I want to form groups of id3, based on match criteria in id1_list and id2_list. Basically each row describes a composite object that has been created using other objects whose id information is listed in id1_list and id2_list. id1_list and id2_list are aligned, so that pairs created by zip(id1_list, id2_list) describe the contributing objects.
Next, we have the merge_data table. This table describes equivalences between those contributing objects (the ones tagged by (id1, id2) pairs). So e.g. the first column of merge_data:
(1, "A", ((1, 2), (3, 4)))

says that at time 1, for objects with id1=A, the objects with id2 in the set (1, 2) should be considered "matches". Likewise for (3, 4). These sets will always be disjoint, if that helps.
So the goal is, for each time t, collect all the rows in data and merge_data for that time, then use merge_data to figure out which rows of data "match". And then output a table of id3 groups that are formed by that criteria at each time group, merging all matches into groups so long as any "link" exists.
I am happy to restructure any of this data to make some sort of clever pandas merge operation do everything efficiently. Or maybe some graph algorithm. But so far all I came up with was the very slow brute force solution above.

Ok so following the basic idea suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/79112475/1447953 but just fixing it up so it works, I came up with this:
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Inputs
columns = ["time", "id1_list", "id2_list", "id3"]
data = [(1, ("A", "B"), (1, 2), 1),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (2, 3), 2),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (4, 5), 3),
        (1, ("A", "B"), (6, 7), 4),        
        (1, ("A", "C"), (1, 1), 5),
        (2, ("A", "B"), (1, 3), 1),
        (2, ("A", "B"), (2, 3), 2),        
        (2, ("A", "B"), (4, 3), 3),
        (2, ("A", "C"), (1, 1), 4)]

merge_cols = ["time", "id1", "id2_lists"]
merge_data = [(1, "A", ((1, 2), (3, 4))),
              (1, "B", ((3, 5),)),
              (2, "A", ((1, 2), (3, 4))),
              (2, "B", ((3, 5),))]

# Create DataFrames
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df_merge_data = pd.DataFrame(merge_data, columns=merge_cols)

def find_connected_components(group):
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    # Build the graph
    for _, row in group.iterrows():
        id1s = row['id1_list']
        id2s = row['id2_list']
        id3 = row['id3']
        
        connected = False
        for id1, id2 in zip(id1s, id2s):
            matches = df_merge_data.query("time == @group.name and id1 == @id1")['id2_lists']
            if not matches.empty:
                for match_group in matches.item():
                    if id2 in match_group:
                        G.add_node(id3, tag="id3")
                        G.add_node(match_group, tag="id2_group")
                        G.add_edge(id3, match_group)
                        connected = True
                        break
                        
        if not connected:
            G.add_node(id3, tag="id3")  # Not connected
    return [list(c for c in component if G.nodes[c]["tag"]=="id3") for component in nx.connected_components(G)]

# Group by time and apply the function
output = df_data.groupby("time").apply(find_connected_components, include_groups=False)

print(output)

# Prepare the final output format
result = [(time, tuple(sorted(map(tuple, components)))) for time, components in output.items()]

# Finally convert to DataFrame
final_output = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["time", "id3_lists"])

# And display the output
print(final_output)

This is much faster than my original terrible solution. It's still not blazingly fast when run over many "timestep" groups with small graphs in each, I suspect something better can be done using a clever pandas merge in there somewhere (perhaps a fancy merge to figure out all the graph edges using pandas, then building one big graph with different components for each time group to work out the final groupings) but this is good enough for my current use case.
